# Accurev: Restore workspace to older version

Tags: accurev

I'm a brand new to Accurev and I'm having many troubles with it.  One of the developers I'm working with has promoted bad code (things are now broken that weren't before) for 2 months on a stream, and I'm wanting to get a copy of the original code before any changes were made to it.

I currently have a workspace, and whenever the other developer creates code, I pull his changes into this workspace attempting to fix the bugs.  These changes are promoted to an existing issue within Accurev.

Is there any way I can perhaps create a second workspace and obtain a copy of the original code (before any changes were made)?  My target date is March 14th.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, I right-clicked the stream >> New Snapshot.
I select "Specified" and enter the date (with a relative time).
From the Snapshot, I created a New Workspace which was then populated with previous code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just for clarification, you created a snapshot stream.  This article discusses a similar problem and solution using a time based stream.  https://accurev.wordpress.com/tag/time-based-stream/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you revert or demote the bad code that was promoted into the stream (Depending on what version of AccuRev you are using).  This would put the stream back into the state it was before the promotion occurred.

Below are some suggested readings on the related topics.

[Best way to "un-promote" files in Accurev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406329/best-way-to-un-promote-files-in-accurev)

https://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/accurev/w/wiki/26745/purge-revert-and-demote

https://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/accurev/w/accurev_knowledge_base/25951/how-to-revert-changes-in-a-stream

https://community.microfocus.com/borland/managetrack/accurev/w/accurev_knowledge_base/26079/what-is-the-proper-way-to-revert-by-change-package

Comment: Unfortunately this is not viable because between now and March 14th, the code needs to be included in the production phase.  By reverting all those changes (other than locally saving the versions), all the code between March 14th and now would be lost.  Unfortunately, it's super bad code, but some of it is still usable and sadly, it's my job to fix the bad code.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could create a time-based stream below the one with the bad code. Set a time basis that predates the bad promote.

Comment: Hi! This is the closest solution I have, but I'm not sure how to execute it... I'm not really sure what a time-based stream is.  I apologize for being an amateur at Accurev!