# Looking for accurev clear client cache script

Tags: caching, accurev

I was reading a post [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19201/accurev-scm&ved=0ahUKEwjjxMaEtfvMAhVMx2MKHQtMC1UQFggaMAA&usg=AFQjCNHwyDx41BzicaCZDx1xDaI3yFL_3w&sig2=poyTA70T2tAhx2hbPTwsbw) and @chaboud commented the following:

> went to an "Advanced Accurev topics" talk, and the first tidbit was a
>   large shell command for clearing out Accurev's client-side
>   caching/sync mechanism to correct for when Accurev updates silently
>   fail to pull down files that should be updated.

Does anyone know of this script or have a copy? I have been looking through accurev documentation and online and so far no luck on this script.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan

I have never heard of this script and I worked for AccuRev.

I am guessing someone (outside of AccuRev) created a script which manually updates a workspace when an update would fail.